# Mupdf Encryption Decryption Issue

Tags: c++, c, pdf, mupdf

I am facing some issues while creating a build for Mupdf to read encrypted pdf files. I am seeing the file, pdf_crypt.c to understand how this can be done. But i cannot understand how to do it.

If i put it in plain terms,

1. I will be encrypting my pdf with a AES 256 bit key.
2. Where should i put the AES key in pdf_crypt.c, so that mupdf can read the file by decrypting it at runtime ?

I am posting the pdf_crypt.c file for reference..

```
            #include "mupdf/pdf.h"

            enum
            {
                PDF_CRYPT_NONE,
                PDF_CRYPT_RC4,
                PDF_CRYPT_AESV2,
                PDF_CRYPT_AESV3,
                PDF_CRYPT_UNKNOWN,
            };

            enum
            {
                PDF_PERM_PRINT = 1 << 2,
                PDF_PERM_CHANGE = 1 << 3,
                PDF_PERM_COPY = 1 << 4,
                PDF_PERM_NOTES = 1 << 5,
                PDF_PERM_FILL_FORM = 1 << 8,
                PDF_PERM_ACCESSIBILITY = 1 << 9,
                PDF_PERM_ASSEMBLE = 1 << 10,
                PDF_PERM_HIGH_RES_PRINT = 1 << 11,
                PDF_DEFAULT_PERM_FLAGS = 0xfffc
            };

            typedef struct pdf_crypt_filter_s pdf_crypt_filter;

            struct pdf_crypt_filter_s
            {
                int method;
                int length;
            };

            struct pdf_crypt_s
            {
                pdf_obj *id;

                int v;
                int length;
                pdf_obj *cf;
                pdf_crypt_filter stmf;
                pdf_crypt_filter strf;

                int r;
                unsigned char o[48];
                unsigned char u[48];
                unsigned char oe[32];
                unsigned char ue[32];
                int p;
                int encrypt_metadata;

                unsigned char key[32]; /* decryption key generated from password */
            };

            static void pdf_parse_crypt_filter(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt_filter *cf, pdf_crypt *crypt, pdf_obj *name);

            /*
             * Create crypt object for decrypting strings and streams
             * given the Encryption and ID objects.
             */

            pdf_crypt *
            pdf_new_crypt(fz_context *ctx, pdf_obj *dict, pdf_obj *id)
            {
                pdf_crypt *crypt;
                pdf_obj *obj;

                crypt = fz_malloc_struct(ctx, pdf_crypt);

                /* Common to all security handlers (PDF 1.7 table 3.18) */

                obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_Filter);
                if (!pdf_is_name(ctx, obj))
                {
                    pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "unspecified encryption handler");
                }
                if (!pdf_name_eq(ctx, PDF_NAME_Standard, obj) != 0)
                {
                    pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "unknown encryption handler: '%s'", pdf_to_name(ctx, obj));
                }

                crypt->v = 0;
                obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_V);
                if (pdf_is_int(ctx, obj))
                    crypt->v = pdf_to_int(ctx, obj);
                if (crypt->v != 1 && crypt->v != 2 && crypt->v != 4 && crypt->v != 5)
                {
                    pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "unknown encryption version");
                }

                /* Standard security handler (PDF 1.7 table 3.19) */

                obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_R);
                if (pdf_is_int(ctx, obj))
                    crypt->r = pdf_to_int(ctx, obj);
                else if (crypt->v <= 4)
                {
                    fz_warn(ctx, "encryption dictionary missing revision value, guessing...");
                    if (crypt->v < 2)
                        crypt->r = 2;
                    else if (crypt->v == 2)
                        crypt->r = 3;
                    else if (crypt->v == 4)
                        crypt->r = 4;
                }
                else
                {
                    pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "encryption dictionary missing version and revision value");
                }
                if (crypt->r < 1 || crypt->r > 6)
                {
                    int r = crypt->r;
                    pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "unknown crypt revision %d", r);
                }

                obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_O);
                if (pdf_is_string(ctx, obj) && pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj) == 32)
                    memcpy(crypt->o, pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, obj), 32);
                /* /O and /U are supposed to be 48 bytes long for revision 5 and 6, they're often longer, though */
                else if (crypt->r >= 5 && pdf_is_string(ctx, obj) && pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj) >= 48)
                    memcpy(crypt->o, pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, obj), 48);
                else
                {
                    pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "encryption dictionary missing owner password");
                }

                obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_U);
                if (pdf_is_string(ctx, obj) && pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj) == 32)
                    memcpy(crypt->u, pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, obj), 32);
                /* /O and /U are supposed to be 48 bytes long for revision 5 and 6, they're often longer, though */
                else if (crypt->r >= 5 && pdf_is_string(ctx, obj) && pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj) >= 48)
                    memcpy(crypt->u, pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, obj), 48);
                else if (pdf_is_string(ctx, obj) && pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj) < 32)
                {
                    fz_warn(ctx, "encryption password key too short (%d)", pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj));
                    memcpy(crypt->u, pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, obj), pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj));
                }
                else
                {
                    pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "encryption dictionary missing user password");
                }

                obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_P);
                if (pdf_is_int(ctx, obj))
                    crypt->p = pdf_to_int(ctx, obj);
                else
                {
                    fz_warn(ctx, "encryption dictionary missing permissions");
                    crypt->p = 0xfffffffc;
                }

                if (crypt->r == 5 || crypt->r == 6)
                {
                    obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_OE);
                    if (!pdf_is_string(ctx, obj) || pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj) != 32)
                    {
                        pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                        fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "encryption dictionary missing owner encryption key");
                    }
                    memcpy(crypt->oe, pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, obj), 32);

                    obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_UE);
                    if (!pdf_is_string(ctx, obj) || pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj) != 32)
                    {
                        pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                        fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "encryption dictionary missing user encryption key");
                    }
                    memcpy(crypt->ue, pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, obj), 32);
                }

                crypt->encrypt_metadata = 1;
                obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_EncryptMetadata);
                if (pdf_is_bool(ctx, obj))
                    crypt->encrypt_metadata = pdf_to_bool(ctx, obj);

                /* Extract file identifier string */

                if (pdf_is_array(ctx, id) && pdf_array_len(ctx, id) == 2)
                {
                    obj = pdf_array_get(ctx, id, 0);
                    if (pdf_is_string(ctx, obj))
                        crypt->id = pdf_keep_obj(ctx, obj);
                }
                else
                    fz_warn(ctx, "missing file identifier, may not be able to do decryption");

                /* Determine encryption key length */

                crypt->length = 40;
                if (crypt->v == 2 || crypt->v == 4)
                {
                    obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_Length);
                    if (pdf_is_int(ctx, obj))
                        crypt->length = pdf_to_int(ctx, obj);

                    /* work-around for pdf generators that assume length is in bytes */
                    if (crypt->length < 40)
                        crypt->length = crypt->length * 8;

                    if (crypt->length % 8 != 0)
                    {
                        pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                        fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "invalid encryption key length");
                    }
                    if (crypt->length < 40 || crypt->length > 128)
                    {
                        pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                        fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "invalid encryption key length");
                    }
                }

                if (crypt->v == 5)
                    crypt->length = 256;

                if (crypt->v == 1 || crypt->v == 2)
                {
                    crypt->stmf.method = PDF_CRYPT_RC4;
                    crypt->stmf.length = crypt->length;

                    crypt->strf.method = PDF_CRYPT_RC4;
                    crypt->strf.length = crypt->length;
                }

                if (crypt->v == 4 || crypt->v == 5)
                {
                    crypt->stmf.method = PDF_CRYPT_NONE;
                    crypt->stmf.length = crypt->length;

                    crypt->strf.method = PDF_CRYPT_NONE;
                    crypt->strf.length = crypt->length;

                    obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_CF);
                    if (pdf_is_dict(ctx, obj))
                    {
                        crypt->cf = pdf_keep_obj(ctx, obj);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        crypt->cf = NULL;
                    }

                    fz_try(ctx)
                    {
                        obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_StmF);
                        if (pdf_is_name(ctx, obj))
                            pdf_parse_crypt_filter(ctx, &crypt->stmf, crypt, obj);

                        obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_StrF);
                        if (pdf_is_name(ctx, obj))
                            pdf_parse_crypt_filter(ctx, &crypt->strf, crypt, obj);
                    }
                    fz_catch(ctx)
                    {
                        pdf_drop_crypt(ctx, crypt);
                        fz_rethrow_message(ctx, "cannot parse string crypt filter (%d %d R)", pdf_to_num(ctx, obj), pdf_to_gen(ctx, obj));
                    }

                    /* in crypt revision 4, the crypt filter determines the key length */
                    if (crypt->strf.method != PDF_CRYPT_NONE)
                        crypt->length = crypt->stmf.length;
                }

                return crypt;
            }

            void
            pdf_drop_crypt(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt *crypt)
            {
                pdf_drop_obj(ctx, crypt->id);
                pdf_drop_obj(ctx, crypt->cf);
                fz_free(ctx, crypt);
            }

            /*
             * Parse a CF dictionary entry (PDF 1.7 table 3.22)
             */

            static void
            pdf_parse_crypt_filter(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt_filter *cf, pdf_crypt *crypt, pdf_obj *name)
            {
                pdf_obj *obj;
                pdf_obj *dict;
                int is_identity = (pdf_name_eq(ctx, name, PDF_NAME_Identity));
                int is_stdcf = (!is_identity && pdf_name_eq(ctx, name, PDF_NAME_StdCF));

                if (!is_identity && !is_stdcf)
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "Crypt Filter not Identity or StdCF (%d %d R)", pdf_to_num(ctx, crypt->cf), pdf_to_gen(ctx, crypt->cf));

                cf->method = PDF_CRYPT_NONE;
                cf->length = crypt->length;

                if (!crypt->cf)
                {
                    cf->method = (is_identity ? PDF_CRYPT_NONE : PDF_CRYPT_RC4);
                    return;
                }

                dict = pdf_dict_get(ctx, crypt->cf, name);
                if (!pdf_is_dict(ctx, dict))
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "cannot parse crypt filter (%d %d R)", pdf_to_num(ctx, crypt->cf), pdf_to_gen(ctx, crypt->cf));

                obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_CFM);
                if (pdf_is_name(ctx, obj))
                {
                    if (pdf_name_eq(ctx, PDF_NAME_None, obj))
                        cf->method = PDF_CRYPT_NONE;
                    else if (pdf_name_eq(ctx, PDF_NAME_V2, obj))
                        cf->method = PDF_CRYPT_RC4;
                    else if (pdf_name_eq(ctx, PDF_NAME_AESV2, obj))
                        cf->method = PDF_CRYPT_AESV2;
                    else if (pdf_name_eq(ctx, PDF_NAME_AESV3, obj))
                        cf->method = PDF_CRYPT_AESV3;
                    else
                        fz_warn(ctx, "unknown encryption method: %s", pdf_to_name(ctx, obj));
                }

                obj = pdf_dict_get(ctx, dict, PDF_NAME_Length);
                if (pdf_is_int(ctx, obj))
                    cf->length = pdf_to_int(ctx, obj);

                /* the length for crypt filters is supposed to be in bytes not bits */
                if (cf->length < 40)
                    cf->length = cf->length * 8;

                if ((cf->length % 8) != 0)
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "invalid key length: %d", cf->length);

                if ((crypt->r == 1 || crypt->r == 2 || crypt->r == 3 || crypt->r == 4) &&
                    (cf->length < 0 || cf->length > 128))
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "invalid key length: %d", cf->length);
                if ((crypt->r == 5 || crypt->r == 6) && cf->length != 256)
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "invalid key length: %d", cf->length);
            }

            /*
             * Compute an encryption key (PDF 1.7 algorithm 3.2)
             */

            static const unsigned char padding[32] =
            {
                0x28, 0xbf, 0x4e, 0x5e, 0x4e, 0x75, 0x8a, 0x41,
                0x64, 0x00, 0x4e, 0x56, 0xff, 0xfa, 0x01, 0x08,
                0x2e, 0x2e, 0x00, 0xb6, 0xd0, 0x68, 0x3e, 0x80,
                0x2f, 0x0c, 0xa9, 0xfe, 0x64, 0x53, 0x69, 0x7a
            };

            static void
            pdf_compute_encryption_key(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt *crypt, unsigned char *password, int pwlen, unsigned char *key)
            {
                unsigned char buf[32];
                unsigned int p;
                int i, n;
                fz_md5 md5;

                n = crypt->length / 8;

                /* Step 1 - copy and pad password string */
                if (pwlen > 32)
                    pwlen = 32;
                memcpy(buf, password, pwlen);
                memcpy(buf + pwlen, padding, 32 - pwlen);

                /* Step 2 - init md5 and pass value of step 1 */
                fz_md5_init(&md5);
                fz_md5_update(&md5, buf, 32);

                /* Step 3 - pass O value */
                fz_md5_update(&md5, crypt->o, 32);

                /* Step 4 - pass P value as unsigned int, low-order byte first */
                p = (unsigned int) crypt->p;
                buf[0] = (p) & 0xFF;
                buf[1] = (p >> 8) & 0xFF;
                buf[2] = (p >> 16) & 0xFF;
                buf[3] = (p >> 24) & 0xFF;
                fz_md5_update(&md5, buf, 4);

                /* Step 5 - pass first element of ID array */
                fz_md5_update(&md5, (unsigned char *)pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, crypt->id), pdf_to_str_len(ctx, crypt->id));

                /* Step 6 (revision 4 or greater) - if metadata is not encrypted pass 0xFFFFFFFF */
                if (crypt->r >= 4)
                {
                    if (!crypt->encrypt_metadata)
                    {
                        buf[0] = 0xFF;
                        buf[1] = 0xFF;
                        buf[2] = 0xFF;
                        buf[3] = 0xFF;
                        fz_md5_update(&md5, buf, 4);
                    }
                }

                /* Step 7 - finish the hash */
                fz_md5_final(&md5, buf);

                /* Step 8 (revision 3 or greater) - do some voodoo 50 times */
                if (crypt->r >= 3)
                {
                    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                    {
                        fz_md5_init(&md5);
                        fz_md5_update(&md5, buf, n);
                        fz_md5_final(&md5, buf);
                    }
                }

                /* Step 9 - the key is the first 'n' bytes of the result */
                memcpy(key, buf, n);
            }

            /*
             * Compute an encryption key (PDF 1.7 ExtensionLevel 3 algorithm 3.2a)
             */

            static void
            pdf_compute_encryption_key_r5(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt *crypt, unsigned char *password, int pwlen, int ownerkey, unsigned char *validationkey)
            {
                unsigned char buffer[128 + 8 + 48];
                fz_sha256 sha256;
                fz_aes aes;

                /* Step 2 - truncate UTF-8 password to 127 characters */

                if (pwlen > 127)
                    pwlen = 127;

                /* Step 3/4 - test password against owner/user key and compute encryption key */

                memcpy(buffer, password, pwlen);
                if (ownerkey)
                {
                    memcpy(buffer + pwlen, crypt->o + 32, 8);
                    memcpy(buffer + pwlen + 8, crypt->u, 48);
                }
                else
                    memcpy(buffer + pwlen, crypt->u + 32, 8);

                fz_sha256_init(&sha256);
                fz_sha256_update(&sha256, buffer, pwlen + 8 + (ownerkey ? 48 : 0));
                fz_sha256_final(&sha256, validationkey);

                /* Step 3.5/4.5 - compute file encryption key from OE/UE */

                memcpy(buffer + pwlen, crypt->u + 40, 8);

                fz_sha256_init(&sha256);
                fz_sha256_update(&sha256, buffer, pwlen + 8);
                fz_sha256_final(&sha256, buffer);

                /* clear password buffer and use it as iv */
                memset(buffer + 32, 0, sizeof(buffer) - 32);
                if (aes_setkey_dec(&aes, buffer, crypt->length))
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "AES key init failed (keylen=%d)", crypt->length);
                aes_crypt_cbc(&aes, AES_DECRYPT, 32, buffer + 32, ownerkey ? crypt->oe : crypt->ue, crypt->key);
            }

            /*
             * Compute an encryption key (PDF 1.7 ExtensionLevel 8 algorithm)
             *
             * Adobe has not yet released the details, so the algorithm reference is:
             * http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/post/The-undocumented-password-validation-algorithm-of-Adobe-Reader-X
             */

            static void
            pdf_compute_hardened_hash_r6(fz_context *ctx, unsigned char *password, int pwlen, unsigned char salt[16], unsigned char *ownerkey, unsigned char hash[32])
            {
                unsigned char data[(128 + 64 + 48) * 64];
                unsigned char block[64];
                int block_size = 32;
                int data_len = 0;
                int i, j, sum;

                fz_sha256 sha256;
                fz_sha384 sha384;
                fz_sha512 sha512;
                fz_aes aes;

                /* Step 1: calculate initial data block */
                fz_sha256_init(&sha256);
                fz_sha256_update(&sha256, password, pwlen);
                fz_sha256_update(&sha256, salt, 8);
                if (ownerkey)
                    fz_sha256_update(&sha256, ownerkey, 48);
                fz_sha256_final(&sha256, block);

                for (i = 0; i < 64 || i < data[data_len * 64 - 1] + 32; i++)
                {
                    /* Step 2: repeat password and data block 64 times */
                    memcpy(data, password, pwlen);
                    memcpy(data + pwlen, block, block_size);
                    if (ownerkey)
                        memcpy(data + pwlen + block_size, ownerkey, 48);
                    data_len = pwlen + block_size + (ownerkey ? 48 : 0);
                    for (j = 1; j < 64; j++)
                        memcpy(data + j * data_len, data, data_len);

                    /* Step 3: encrypt data using data block as key and iv */
                    if (aes_setkey_enc(&aes, block, 128))
                        fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "AES key init failed (keylen=%d)", 128);
                    aes_crypt_cbc(&aes, AES_ENCRYPT, data_len * 64, block + 16, data, data);

                    /* Step 4: determine SHA-2 hash size for this round */
                    for (j = 0, sum = 0; j < 16; j++)
                        sum += data[j];

                    /* Step 5: calculate data block for next round */
                    block_size = 32 + (sum % 3) * 16;
                    switch (block_size)
                    {
                    case 32:
                        fz_sha256_init(&sha256);
                        fz_sha256_update(&sha256, data, data_len * 64);
                        fz_sha256_final(&sha256, block);
                        break;
                    case 48:
                        fz_sha384_init(&sha384);
                        fz_sha384_update(&sha384, data, data_len * 64);
                        fz_sha384_final(&sha384, block);
                        break;
                    case 64:
                        fz_sha512_init(&sha512);
                        fz_sha512_update(&sha512, data, data_len * 64);
                        fz_sha512_final(&sha512, block);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
                memcpy(hash, block, 32);
            }

            static void
            pdf_compute_encryption_key_r6(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt *crypt, unsigned char *password, int pwlen, int ownerkey, unsigned char *validationkey)
            {
                unsigned char hash[32];
                unsigned char iv[16];
                fz_aes aes;

                if (pwlen > 127)
                    pwlen = 127;

                pdf_compute_hardened_hash_r6(ctx, password, pwlen,
                    (ownerkey ? crypt->o : crypt->u) + 32,
                    ownerkey ? crypt->u : NULL, validationkey);
                pdf_compute_hardened_hash_r6(ctx, password, pwlen,
                    crypt->u + 40, NULL, hash);

                memset(iv, 0, sizeof(iv));
                if (aes_setkey_dec(&aes, hash, 256))
                    fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "AES key init failed (keylen=256)");
                aes_crypt_cbc(&aes, AES_DECRYPT, 32, iv,
                    ownerkey ? crypt->oe : crypt->ue, crypt->key);
            }

            /*
             * Computing the user password (PDF 1.7 algorithm 3.4 and 3.5)
             * Also save the generated key for decrypting objects and streams in crypt->key.
             */

            static void
            pdf_compute_user_password(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt *crypt, unsigned char *password, int pwlen, unsigned char *output)
            {
                if (crypt->r == 2)
                {
                    fz_arc4 arc4;

                    pdf_compute_encryption_key(ctx, crypt, password, pwlen, crypt->key);
                    fz_arc4_init(&arc4, crypt->key, crypt->length / 8);
                    fz_arc4_encrypt(&arc4, output, padding, 32);
                }

                if (crypt->r == 3 || crypt->r == 4)
                {
                    unsigned char xor[32];
                    unsigned char digest[16];
                    fz_md5 md5;
                    fz_arc4 arc4;
                    int i, x, n;

                    n = crypt->length / 8;

                    pdf_compute_encryption_key(ctx, crypt, password, pwlen, crypt->key);

                    fz_md5_init(&md5);
                    fz_md5_update(&md5, padding, 32);
                    fz_md5_update(&md5, (unsigned char*)pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, crypt->id), pdf_to_str_len(ctx, crypt->id));
                    fz_md5_final(&md5, digest);

                    fz_arc4_init(&arc4, crypt->key, n);
                    fz_arc4_encrypt(&arc4, output, digest, 16);

                    for (x = 1; x <= 19; x++)
                    {
                        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                            xor[i] = crypt->key[i] ^ x;
                        fz_arc4_init(&arc4, xor, n);
                        fz_arc4_encrypt(&arc4, output, output, 16);
                    }

                    memcpy(output + 16, padding, 16);
                }

                if (crypt->r == 5)
                {
                    pdf_compute_encryption_key_r5(ctx, crypt, password, pwlen, 0, output);
                }

                if (crypt->r == 6)
                {
                    pdf_compute_encryption_key_r6(ctx, crypt, password, pwlen, 0, output);
                }
            }

            /*
             * Authenticating the user password (PDF 1.7 algorithm 3.6
             * and ExtensionLevel 3 algorithm 3.11)
             * This also has the side effect of saving a key generated
             * from the password for decrypting objects and streams.
             */

            static int
            pdf_authenticate_user_password(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt *crypt, unsigned char *password, int pwlen)
            {
                unsigned char output[32];
                pdf_compute_user_password(ctx, crypt, password, pwlen, output);
                if (crypt->r == 2 || crypt->r == 5 || crypt->r == 6)
                    return memcmp(output, crypt->u, 32) == 0;
                if (crypt->r == 3 || crypt->r == 4)
                    return memcmp(output, crypt->u, 16) == 0;
                return 0;
            }

            /*
             * Authenticating the owner password (PDF 1.7 algorithm 3.7
             * and ExtensionLevel 3 algorithm 3.12)
             * Generates the user password from the owner password
             * and calls pdf_authenticate_user_password.
             */

            static int
            pdf_authenticate_owner_password(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt *crypt, unsigned char *ownerpass, int pwlen)
            {
                unsigned char pwbuf[32];
                unsigned char key[32];
                unsigned char xor[32];
                unsigned char userpass[32];
                int i, n, x;
                fz_md5 md5;
                fz_arc4 arc4;

                if (crypt->r == 5)
                {
                    /* PDF 1.7 ExtensionLevel 3 algorithm 3.12 */
                    pdf_compute_encryption_key_r5(ctx, crypt, ownerpass, pwlen, 1, key);
                    return !memcmp(key, crypt->o, 32);
                }
                else if (crypt->r == 6)
                {
                    /* PDF 1.7 ExtensionLevel 8 algorithm */
                    pdf_compute_encryption_key_r6(ctx, crypt, ownerpass, pwlen, 1, key);
                    return !memcmp(key, crypt->o, 32);
                }

                n = crypt->length / 8;

                /* Step 1 -- steps 1 to 4 of PDF 1.7 algorithm 3.3 */

                /* copy and pad password string */
                if (pwlen > 32)
                    pwlen = 32;
                memcpy(pwbuf, ownerpass, pwlen);
                memcpy(pwbuf + pwlen, padding, 32 - pwlen);

                /* take md5 hash of padded password */
                fz_md5_init(&md5);
                fz_md5_update(&md5, pwbuf, 32);
                fz_md5_final(&md5, key);

                /* do some voodoo 50 times (Revision 3 or greater) */
                if (crypt->r >= 3)
                {
                    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                    {
                        fz_md5_init(&md5);
                        fz_md5_update(&md5, key, 16);
                        fz_md5_final(&md5, key);
                    }
                }

                /* Step 2 (Revision 2) */
                if (crypt->r == 2)
                {
                    fz_arc4_init(&arc4, key, n);
                    fz_arc4_encrypt(&arc4, userpass, crypt->o, 32);
                }

                /* Step 2 (Revision 3 or greater) */
                if (crypt->r >= 3)
                {
                    memcpy(userpass, crypt->o, 32);
                    for (x = 0; x < 20; x++)
                    {
                        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                            xor[i] = key[i] ^ (19 - x);
                        fz_arc4_init(&arc4, xor, n);
                        fz_arc4_encrypt(&arc4, userpass, userpass, 32);
                    }
                }

                return pdf_authenticate_user_password(ctx, crypt, userpass, 32);
            }

            static void pdf_docenc_from_utf8(char *password, const char *utf8, int n)
            {
                int i = 0, k, c;
                while (*utf8 && i + 1 < n)
                {
                    utf8 += fz_chartorune(&c, utf8);
                    for (k = 0; k < 256; k++)
                    {
                        if (c == pdf_doc_encoding[k])
                        {
                            password[i++] = k;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    /* FIXME: drop characters that can't be encoded or return an error? */
                }
                password[i] = 0;
            }

            static void pdf_saslprep_from_utf8(char *password, const char *utf8, int n)
            {
                /* TODO: stringprep with SALSprep profile */
                fz_strlcpy(password, utf8, n);
            }

            int
            pdf_authenticate_password(fz_context *ctx, pdf_document *doc, const char *pwd_utf8)
            {
                char password[2048];

                if (doc->crypt)
                {
                    password[0] = 0;
                    if (pwd_utf8)
                    {
                        if (doc->crypt->r <= 4)
                            pdf_docenc_from_utf8(password, pwd_utf8, sizeof password);
                        else
                            pdf_saslprep_from_utf8(password, pwd_utf8, sizeof password);
                    }

                    if (pdf_authenticate_user_password(ctx, doc->crypt, (unsigned char *)password, strlen(password)))
                        return 1;
                    if (pdf_authenticate_owner_password(ctx, doc->crypt, (unsigned char *)password, strlen(password)))
                        return 1;
                    return 0;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            int
            pdf_needs_password(fz_context *ctx, pdf_document *doc)
            {
                if (!doc->crypt)
                    return 0;
                if (pdf_authenticate_password(ctx, doc, ""))
                    return 0;
                return 1;
            }

            int
            pdf_has_permission(fz_context *ctx, pdf_document *doc, fz_permission p)
            {
                if (!doc->crypt)
                    return 1;
                switch (p)
                {
                case FZ_PERMISSION_PRINT: return doc->crypt->p & PDF_PERM_PRINT;
                case FZ_PERMISSION_COPY: return doc->crypt->p & PDF_PERM_COPY;
                case FZ_PERMISSION_EDIT: return doc->crypt->p & PDF_PERM_CHANGE;
                case FZ_PERMISSION_ANNOTATE: return doc->crypt->p & PDF_PERM_NOTES;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            unsigned char *
            pdf_crypt_key(fz_context *ctx, pdf_document *doc)
            {
                if (doc->crypt)
                    return doc->crypt->key;
                return NULL;
            }

            int
            pdf_crypt_version(fz_context *ctx, pdf_document *doc)
            {
                if (doc->crypt)
                    return doc->crypt->v;
                return 0;
            }

            int pdf_crypt_revision(fz_context *ctx, pdf_document *doc)
            {
                if (doc->crypt)
                    return doc->crypt->r;
                return 0;
            }

            char *
            pdf_crypt_method(fz_context *ctx, pdf_document *doc)
            {
                if (doc->crypt)
                {
                    switch (doc->crypt->strf.method)
                    {
                    case PDF_CRYPT_NONE: return "None";
                    case PDF_CRYPT_RC4: return "RC4";
                    case PDF_CRYPT_AESV2: return "AES";
                    case PDF_CRYPT_AESV3: return "AES";
                    case PDF_CRYPT_UNKNOWN: return "Unknown";
                    }
                }
                return "None";
            }

            int
            pdf_crypt_length(fz_context *ctx, pdf_document *doc)
            {
                if (doc->crypt)
                    return doc->crypt->length;
                return 0;
            }

            /*
             * PDF 1.7 algorithm 3.1 and ExtensionLevel 3 algorithm 3.1a
             *
             * Using the global encryption key that was generated from the
             * password, create a new key that is used to decrypt individual
             * objects and streams. This key is based on the object and
             * generation numbers.
             */

            static int
            pdf_compute_object_key(pdf_crypt *crypt, pdf_crypt_filter *cf, int num, int gen, unsigned char *key, int max_len)
            {
                fz_md5 md5;
                unsigned char message[5];
                int key_len = crypt->length / 8;

                if (key_len > max_len)
                    key_len = max_len;

                if (cf->method == PDF_CRYPT_AESV3)
                {
                    memcpy(key, crypt->key, key_len);
                    return key_len;
                }

                fz_md5_init(&md5);
                fz_md5_update(&md5, crypt->key, key_len);
                message[0] = (num) & 0xFF;
                message[1] = (num >> 8) & 0xFF;
                message[2] = (num >> 16) & 0xFF;
                message[3] = (gen) & 0xFF;
                message[4] = (gen >> 8) & 0xFF;
                fz_md5_update(&md5, message, 5);

                if (cf->method == PDF_CRYPT_AESV2)
                    fz_md5_update(&md5, (unsigned char *)"sAlT", 4);

                fz_md5_final(&md5, key);

                if (key_len + 5 > 16)
                    return 16;
                return key_len + 5;
            }

            /*
             * PDF 1.7 algorithm 3.1 and ExtensionLevel 3 algorithm 3.1a
             *
             * Decrypt all strings in obj modifying the data in-place.
             * Recurse through arrays and dictionaries, but do not follow
             * indirect references.
             */

            static void
            pdf_crypt_obj_imp(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt *crypt, pdf_obj *obj, unsigned char *key, int keylen)
            {
                unsigned char *s;
                int i, n;

                if (pdf_is_indirect(ctx, obj))
                    return;

                if (pdf_is_string(ctx, obj))
                {
                    s = (unsigned char *)pdf_to_str_buf(ctx, obj);
                    n = pdf_to_str_len(ctx, obj);

                    if (crypt->strf.method == PDF_CRYPT_RC4)
                    {
                        fz_arc4 arc4;
                        fz_arc4_init(&arc4, key, keylen);
                        fz_arc4_encrypt(&arc4, s, s, n);
                    }

                    if (crypt->strf.method == PDF_CRYPT_AESV2 || crypt->strf.method == PDF_CRYPT_AESV3)
                    {
                        if (n == 0)
                        {
                            /* Empty strings are permissible */
                        }
                        else if (n & 15 || n < 32)
                            fz_warn(ctx, "invalid string length for aes encryption");
                        else
                        {
                            unsigned char iv[16];
                            fz_aes aes;
                            memcpy(iv, s, 16);
                            if (aes_setkey_dec(&aes, key, keylen * 8))
                                fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "AES key init failed (keylen=%d)", keylen * 8);
                            aes_crypt_cbc(&aes, AES_DECRYPT, n - 16, iv, s + 16, s);
                            /* delete space used for iv and padding bytes at end */
                            if (s[n - 17] < 1 || s[n - 17] > 16)
                                fz_warn(ctx, "aes padding out of range");
                            else
                                pdf_set_str_len(ctx, obj, n - 16 - s[n - 17]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if (pdf_is_array(ctx, obj))
                {
                    n = pdf_array_len(ctx, obj);
                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        pdf_crypt_obj_imp(ctx, crypt, pdf_array_get(ctx, obj, i), key, keylen);
                    }
                }

                else if (pdf_is_dict(ctx, obj))
                {
                    n = pdf_dict_len(ctx, obj);
                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        pdf_crypt_obj_imp(ctx, crypt, pdf_dict_get_val(ctx, obj, i), key, keylen);
                    }
                }
            }

            void
            pdf_crypt_obj(fz_context *ctx, pdf_crypt *crypt, pdf_obj *obj, int num, int gen)
            {
                unsigned char key[32];
                int len;

                len = pdf_compute_object_key(crypt, &crypt->strf, num, gen, key, 32);

                pdf_crypt_obj_imp(ctx, crypt, obj, key, len);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I should say a few words about licensing. MuPDF is licensed under 2 different licences.

The first is the GNU AGPL. This is a very strict license that places lots of requirements upon you for you to be able to use the code. The biggest requirement is that anyone that gets a copy of your app has the rights to demand the full source code for your *entire* app. This would clearly include any decryption key, meaning your DRM would be useless. You should read the license carefully to make sure it's suitable for what you want to do before continuing.

If you use MuPDF under the GNU AGPL license, we cannot guarantee you any support.

If you can't abide by the terms of the GNU AGPL, then you can obtain a commercial license from Artifex (mail sales@artifex.com with as many details of your project as possible and they'll talk to you about a customised licensing proposal). This frees you from all the onerous terms of the GNU AGPL.

If you are unable to comply with the GNU AGPL, or you are unwilling to pay for a commercial license, then you cannot use MuPDF.

Now, onto the actual question...

pdf_crypt.c implements the standard decryption handlers used in PDF. It sounds to me like you want to do something non-standard. As such, pdf_crypt.c will require some changes.

One technique would be to create a perfectly normal encrypted PDF file using a password. Your app can provide the password to MuPDF as it opens the file, and decryption will work seamlessly for you. The user need not even know that there is a password involved. In terms of coding this is the simplest possible way to go.

Another technique would be to do block based encryption of the file, and to decrypt blocks of the file as you load it - we have customers who do DRM in their products like this.

It's impossible to give you more information without knowing more about what you want to do.

If you wish to discuss this problem more, your best bet is probably to come to the #ghostscript irc channel (see mupdf.com for a link that will open this in your web browser).